# Can I build DLLs into a Class Library

Tags: c#, dll

I am creating a web application in Visual Studio 2010 (C#).

I have one project that contains several classes that are shared between multiple projects.

Within that project I also have the AJAXToolkit dll.

Each of my other projects has a reference pointing to the shared project.

But I also have to setup a reference to the AjaxToolkit.dll in order to build.

Is there a way to have the AjaxToolkit.dll included in the shared project reference, so I don't have to reference both? (Basically only have the one shared dll in stead of both)

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are looking for [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630).

> ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly. It works on executables and DLLs alike and comes with several options for controlling the processing and format of the output